# Why would python setup.py ignore --prefix?

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a python project using setuptools via setup.py for installation. When I provide no arguments to `python setup.py install` things install into the standard `--user` directory in `~/.local`. However, when I provide `--prefix ~/opt/myproject`, that gets ignored by the install command and things still get pushed into `~/.local`. It seems that whatever directories I specify, the 'user' scheme is selected.

I'm not doing anything special in my setup.py, but I can post whatever code is relevant to help debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this behavior with [certain versions](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=463834) of `setuptools`. If you're importing from `setuptools` try importing from `distutils` instead and see if that solves it.

Comment: With a different version of `setuptools`, or using `distutils`, this problem goes away, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is `--prefix ~/opt/myproject` exactly how your are using the command? I would recommend two things. First, the --prefix argument needs an equal sign, so it should look like this:

> --prefix=~/opt/myproject

Second, I would use the full path. I'm not sure if using the `~` will work, it might, but you'll probably have better luck using the full path:

> python setup.py install --prefix=/home/username/opt/myproject

You can read more about the prefix scheme [here](http://docs.python.org/2/install/#alternate-installation-unix-the-prefix-scheme).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have default options in ~/.pydistutils.cfg?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, that file does not exist at all.

Comment: Can you give more details about your project layout, the setup.py file contents and the exact command you run with its output/result?